# Want to know image's original size and assign via attribute in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to know my dynamic image's dimensions and set true values on images. So I tried a function, like this:

```
$().ready(function() {
    imageSize();
});
// Assign width/height to img
function imageSize() {
    // Specify image dimensions
    $('img').each(function() {
        var findImgWidth = $(this).width();
        var findImgHeight = $(this).height();

        $(this).attr('width', findImgWidth);
        $(this).attr('height', findImgHeight);
    });
}
```

Well, it works for assign but not calculate dimensions. Every image's dimensions is `0px`
How can I fix it?

Comment: Use the window onload event instead, you'd have to wait for the images to load to get their dimensions.

Comment: @Shikkediel yes! this is it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(document).ready()` runs when the DOM is parsed, but doesn't wait for the images to be loaded.

Add a `load` handler to each element to set its attributes when it gets loaded, rather than doing them all in a loop.

```
function imagesize() {
    $('img').on('load', function() {
        $(this).attr({
            'width': $(this).width() + "px",
            'height': $(this).height() + "px"
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value as a number, parseFloat(img value)

Hope this helps